# tkinter wont refresh widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to write a program that has only a button, and after pressing that, program will start making 3 labels and then change the color of each one every 1 second only once.

It looks very simple and I wrote the following code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep


def function():
    mylist=list()
    for i in range(3):
        new_label=tk.Label(window,text='* * *',bg='yellow')
        new_label.pack()
        mylist.append(new_label)
    print('First state finished')
    sleep(1)
    for label in mylist:
        label.config(bg='red')
        print('one label changed')
        sleep(1)
    
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('300x300')

btn=tk.Button(window,text='start',command=function)
btn.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

First the app is look like this (that is OK):

[image]

Second its look like this (its not OK because its print on the terminal but didn't update the lable) :

[image]

Third its look like this (at the end the app must be look like this and its OK) :

[image]

But I need to see the changes in the moment and use sleep for that reason.
Thank you All.

Comment: Sleep puts the entire program to sleep, including its ability to refresh the display.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes you right but I put sleep for Human understanding only

Comment: Do you want to change colour one at a time or all colours in together.
i.e. 
after 1st second - change colour of label 1
after 2nd second - change colour of label 2
and after 3rd second - change colour of label 3

Comment: @Meritor one by one, not togather

Comment: sorry.. one more question.. do you want to keep changing the colour, every one second after start is pressed or just once of.. once all label changes the color that's all

Comment: @Meritor No, it only takes one time for all the labels to change color one by one, and then the program ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use .after(delay, callback) method of the tkinter to set the colour.

Hope this is what you want.

```
import tkinter as tk


def start():
    global mylist
    mylist = list()
    for i in range(3):
        new_label = tk.Label(window, text='* * *', bg='yellow')
        new_label.pack()
        mylist.append(new_label)

    delay = 1000 # delay in seconds
    for label in mylist:
        # Additional delay so that next color change 
        # is scheduled after previous label color change
        delay += 1000 
        schedule_color_change(delay, label)


def schedule_color_change(delay, label):
    print("schedule color change for:", label)
    label.after(delay, set_color, label)



def set_color(label):
    print("setting color of:", label)
    label.config(bg="red")


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('300x300')
btn = tk.Button(window, text='start', command=start)
btn.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for your guide about `after` method and your code has very creativity :)

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to use `lambda` with `after` if you only need positional arguments: `label.after(delay, set_color, label)` is a little less complex and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The problem is your `sleep(1)`, because it's a function that suspends the execution of the current thread for a set number of seconds, so it's like there is a stop to the whole script

**Solution**

The solution is to instantiate Thread with a target function, call start(), and let it start working. So you have to use `timer` which is included in the threading, then a timer from the threading module (`import threading`)

Inside the first "for" loop, remove your sleep(1) and write for example `Time_Start_Here = threading.Timer (2, function_2)` and then of course T`ime_Start_Here.start()` to start.

```
start_time=threading.Timer(1,function_2)
start_time.start()
```

Instead you have to remove the second "for" loop and write what's inside ... inside the new function that will be called. Next you need to create the function

```
def function_2():
    for label in mylist:
        label.config(bg='red')
        label.pack()
        print('one label changed')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Now I have several good answers that I do not know which one to use, which is great!!

Comment: Threading is overkill for something this simple You're also courting disaster by interacting with a widget from another thread. It often will work, but it can also cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

As *Meritor* guided me, I followed the `after` method and wrote the following recursive code without sleep :

```
import tkinter as tk


def recursive(i, listt):
    lbl = listt[i]
    if i >= 0:
        lbl.config(bg='orange')
        i -= 1
        lbl.after(500, recursive, i, listt)


def function():
    mylist = list()
    for i in range(3):
        new_label = tk.Label(window, text='* * *', bg='yellow')
        new_label.pack()
        mylist.append(new_label)
    print('all label created')
    # 2 is length of list minus 1
    recursive(2, mylist)


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('300x300')

tk.Button(window, text='start', command=function).pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Most likely my code is not optimized because it uses recursive and if you know anything better please tell me

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve here with recursive. It's repeatedly setting  orange color every 500 milliseconds.
on the side note, recursive is not a correct word here though. Its not recursive, its scheduling the same function call every time .after() is called.

Comment: This isn't actually recursive, since the function doesn't call itself. It simply puts itself in a queue before returning.